# Reproducing SE verbatim in TeX documents

Tags: verbatim, code, displaystyle

In a LaTeX document, how does one produce a verbatim-type expression like in the StackExchange website, for writing code? For example, `example`, where you get a grey box highlighting the text. I know about `\verb`, but not sure if this is attainable. Any ideas? Has this been answered before?

Apologies if I am using the wrong terms, I would be happy to receive any suggestions on how to learn about this.

Comment: Do you mean a package like [Minted](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted)?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main solutions: `minted` and `listings`. They give similar results, but `minted` is harder to set up because you need 1) a specific Python module installed and 2) to open a security risk in LaTeX by activating shell escape.

So I'll suggest `listings`, which works out of the box with no external installation and no special option. Here's a small sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, numbers=left, frame=single]
# A Python example
import numpy as np
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 150)
\end{lstlisting}
    
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[LaTeX]TeX}, numbers=left, frame=single]
% A LaTeX example
\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Of course there are options to tweak the appearence by language, including colored syntax highlighting.

Inside the `lstlisting` environment, it *is* verbatim code so by default you can't have LaTeX commands that you want executed. There is a solution if necessary, look for the `escapechar` option in the documentation. I use to insert `\label` commands in the code so that I can reference specific lines later on.